# How to get the difference in time in seconds?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

In my C# code, I get the time using **DateTime.Now**, and again later. But now how can I get the difference between those two date objects in seconds as an integer value?

Comment: Keep in mind that the precision of `DateTime` is only about 16ms, so if having your time +/- 32 ms is too much variance yous houldn't be using `DateTime`, you should be using `StopWatch`.  (And probably even then you should be using `StopWatch`.)

Comment: yes I am now using stopwatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using a `StopWatch` object?

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

// execute some code here....

parserWatch.Stop();
```

And then you can get the seconds like this:

```
int seconds = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000;
```

Or a `TimeSpan` object, if you want:

```
TimeSpan time = watch.Elapsed;
```

Comment: You want to divide by 1000, not multiply.

Answer (score 11):

```
long seconds = (long)(then - now).TotalSeconds;
```

Subtracting two `DateTime`s will return a `TimeSpan` object, which has an integer `Seconds` property (between 0 and 60) and a floating-point `TotalSeconds` property.

Comment: I really, really like the idea that his application might run for more than `Int32.MaxValue` _seconds_, so we'd better use a `long`. No more unix-time overflow problems!

Answer (score 3):

Another way using [Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.subtract.aspx) method:

```
 double second = then.Subtract(now).TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 double starttime = Environment.TickCount;
  // do sth
 double endtime = Environment.TickCount;
 double millisecs = endtime - starttime;  // this is in milliseconds.
 double seconds = (millisecs / 1000);         //  this is in seconds.
```

Comment: `TickCount` can overflow (will do so once per 49.7 days (or 1.63 months) if computer is never restarted), so if by accident an overflow takes place during `// do sth`, you get a silly ouput.